# Save HTML form drop down option value attribute as HTML instead of special character (&amp; instead of &)

Tags: php, html, forms, select, mysqli

I have a input form which has a select field. In the options you have a value attribute which I have a special character included. This is the code:

```
<option id="Applicant_Industry" value="Engineering &amp; Manufacturing | Food &amp; Snacks">Food &amp; Snacks</option>
```

When is stores to the database using PHP and mySQLi it saves it as its special character of &.

I was wondering if there is a way to allow PHP to save the HTML value instead of the special character? (e.g. & amp;)

I hope that makes sense!

Thanks!

Comment: `$html = html_entity_decode("Engineering &amp; Manufacturing | Food &amp; Snacks");`

Comment: Actually it is the opposite function that is needed htmlentities()

Comment: @BCartolo How so? `"it saves it as its special character"` ... `"is (there) a way to ... save the HTML value instead"`

Answer (score 1):

You can't/shouldn't really, I suggest using the php function `htmlspecialchars_decode()`

Like this you can store the HTML in a safer way and decode it when echoing the data wherever you need it, and if you really have to save it use the function before inserting it.
Hope this helps